# Kubernetes: Limit number of simultaneous deployments

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, yaml

Is there a way to limit the number of deployments a Kubernetes cluster will implement at once? With rolling deployments and 100% uptime, it's possible that updating all deployments at once could overload the nodes.

I know it is possible to limit the number of pods deployed per-namespace, but i was wondering if it is also possible to limit simultaneous deployments in a similar way. Say, for example, maximum of 10 deployments at once.

I could probably script out a limit to the number of deployments I send to the k8s API at once, but it would be nice if there was a setting I could use instead.

Comment: Do you need to limit initial deployment(replication controller creating desired number of pods) or rolling update?

Comment: how did you solve this finally?

Comment: i haven't yet, it's not blocking other things so i haven't gotten around to solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing coming to my mind is to use resource [limits and requests](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#resource-types) to make sure you're not overloading the cluster. This way, even if you update all the deployments, some pods will be in "pending" state until other deployments are successfully updated.

Comment: Using limits might not solve the problem is there is a huge difference between resources used to start and resources used to run. If you run java (Spring Boot) applications, they typically consume lots of resources during start (like 2 - 3 cpus for instance) but when they run they only consume roughly around 0.2 CPU. If you now configure a limit to allow start, you are wasting capacity at your node. If you limit the resources to the run usage you have the same issue again.

Answer (score 0):

This solution can be helpful

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 50%
  template:
    ---
```

Setup RollingUpdate in your deployment.

```
rollingUpdate:
  maxUnavailable: 50%

// The maximum number of pods that can be unavailable during the update.
// Value can be an absolute number (ex: 5) or a percentage of desired pods (ex: 10%).
// Absolute number is calculated from percentage by rounding down.
// This can not be 0 if MaxSurge is 0.
// Defaults to 25%.
// Example: when this is set to 30%, the old RC can be scaled down to 70% of desired pods
// immediately when the rolling update starts. Once new pods are ready, old RC
// can be scaled down further, followed by scaling up the new RC, ensuring
// that the total number of pods available at all times during the update is at
// least 70% of desired pods.
```

In this way you can limit simultaneous deployments.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but I assume that one can do this with an Admission controller. Set up an ExternalAdmissionWebhook:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/extensible-admission-controllers/#external-admission-webhooks

When it receives an admissionReview request for a Deployment object, check the count and state of Deployments through the API, and reject the request if the criteria for concurrent Deployments are exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

If you set resource requests on all your pods k8 will queue pods if resources are saturated